# How do I unselect all selected CheckBoxes in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I want to uncheck all selected CheckBoxes from DataGridView which is generated dynamically?

I tried like following

```
for (int i = 0; i < MygridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)MygridView.Rows[i].Cells[0];
   if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue)
   {
    // (row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Index] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).value = false;
    Need to unchecked all checked checkboxes 
   }
}
```

Or Is there any other method?

Comment: Why the if? cell.Value = false or = cell.FalseValue  should do.. Or are they TriState? then leave the if but use the cell variable you have prepared..

Comment: Also what is generated? But other than that, no you need a loop and casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in MygridView)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)item.Cells[0];

            cell.Value = false;
        }
```

Comment: Correction to the above that I just ran across:  add .Rows to MygridView in the code above.